# Deutsche Wörter mit allen deutschen Sonderbuchstaben

Tags: umlaut, eszett, curiosity

Ich suche deutsche Wörter, welche alle der folgenden Buchstaben enthalten: ä, ö, ü, ß. Es geht um primäre oder zusammengesetzte, aber Sinn ergebende Wörter.

Das einzige, worauf ich bis jetzt kam, ist **Süßölgefäß**.

Comment: Füllkörpersäule ist nah. Füg was Sinnvolles mit *ß* hinzu :)

Comment: _Mittelsächsisches Lößhügelland_ ist ein Begriff, aber in zwei Wörtern.

Comment: Kannst Du *Sinn ergeben* irgendwie definieren? *Süßölgefäß* kann ja in gegebenem Kontext durchaus Sinn ergeben. Falls es Dir hilft, Deine Kriterien zu spezifizieren, schmeiße ich noch *Übergrößenänderungsschneiderei* ins Rennen. Benutzt vermutlich niemand, ergibt aber Sinn.

Comment: Ja, das ergibt Sinn. Ein gutes Beispiel! Keinen Sinn ergäben z.B. Käsemückentöpfereiruß oder Überseezentimetermaßgähnösterreicher.

Comment: Du hast mich da auf eine gute Idee für ein tatsächlich benutztes Wort gebracht, @Wrzlprmft. Antwort folgt.

Comment: Was ist mit dem Klassiker _Ölrückstoßabdämpfung_?

Comment: Den hab ich nicht gekannt, go on and post it as answer :)

Comment: @Ingmar: »*Heizölrückstoßabdämpfung*« enthält sogar 24 der 30 deutschen Buchstaben (es fehlen nur j,q,v,w,x,y).

Comment: @Ingmar: We already have [a question as to whether that word is actually used](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/148/2594).

Comment: +1 für _Käsemückentöpfereiruß_

Comment: Related: [Which German word contains the most ä, ö, ü, and ß in any variation?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/6264/9551)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Oh Mann, was für ein Freitag! Da kommt man motiviert in die Firma, um der Arbeitswoche die letzten paar Stunden abzuringen, und dann gibt’s nur Probleme.

- Seit ein paar Tagen ist in der Produktion eine Maschine defekt. Bei
  der heutigen Lieferung des Ersatzteils stellt sich heraus, dass etwas
  mit der Bestellung schiefgegangen ist. Im Paket befand sich eine
  **Großfräsmaschinenöffnungstür**, die nicht an unsere Kleinfräsmaschinenöffnung montiert werden kann. Da hilft’s auch nicht,
  wenn der alte **Gehäuseöffnungstürschließer** mit beiden Türen
  kompatibel ist.
- Es ist zwar immer etwas Aufwand, das große Schwimmbecken zu befüllen,
  aber das große gemeinschaftliche **Ganzkörperkäsesoßentauchfrühstück** mit der gesamten Belegschaft ist etwas, worauf alle die ganze Woche hinfiebern (und vermutlich der einzige Grund, warum überhaupt so viele freitags da sind). Zugegeben, einige sind immer noch mürrisch darüber, dass es neuerdings nur einmal wöchentlich stattfindet, aber dafür gibt’s jetzt exklusivere Käsesorten.
  Und dann das! Das Frühstück wurde abgesagt, weil der Koch seinen **Käsesoßenrührlöffel** nicht mitgebracht hat. Dieses essentielle Werkzeug zur Käsesoßenzubereitung hat eine empfindliche Antihaftbeschichtung. Weil die zum Transport zu verwendende **Käsesoßenlöffelschutzhülle** nicht aufzufinden war, musste der Löffel zu Hause bleiben und das Frühstück musste leider ausfallen.
- Von da an spielten wohl alle mit dem Gedanken, heute spontan noch ein paar Überstunden abzubauen. Dieser wurde sogleich durch eine **Großraumbüroklimagerätestörung** bekräftigt. Bei der Affenhitze hat es keiner mehr lange ausgehalten.
- Um mich von diesem Tag zu erholen und das Desaster in der Kantine vergessen zu machen, hab ich mir daheim gleich ein paar **Eichhörnchenfüßefleischhäppchen** aufgetaut und verdrückt. Mmhhhh, lecker. Mit einem großen Klecks Meerrettich.

Comment: Ich sehe da ehrlich gesagt kein einziges Sinn ergebendes Wort unter den Wörtern, die alle deutschen Sonderbuchstaben enthalten.

Comment: Ha, ha. Was für ein Freitag! Du hast soeben den Titel "meine Lieblingsantwort" gewonnen! Dabei sind durchaus Wörter, die Sinn haben (z.B. Großraumbüroklimagerätestörung) und vor allen Dingen hast du ein großes Schmunzeln auf meinem Gesicht gezaubert. Danke dafür :)

Answer (score 33):

Ein [*Übergrößengeschäft*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%C3%BCbergr%C3%B6%C3%9Fengesch%C3%A4ft) ist ein Laden, der sich auf Kleidung oder Schuhe in Übergrößen spezialisiert hat.

Comment: Na wenn das kein gutes Beispiel ist. Und Glückwunsch zu 10k reputation score!

Comment: Es macht Sinn, es findet tatsächlich Verwendung und es bricht einem nicht die Zunge, sehr schön!

Answer (score 13):

> Ein Mikrofilmprinter ist ein **Rückvergrößerungsgerät** zur Erstellung von Papierkopien aus Mikrofilmen. Analoge Rückvergrößerungsgeräte werden heute nahezu komplett durch Mikrofilmscanner ersetzt.

Quelle: [http://www.rosenberger-gruppe.de/glossar](http://www.rosenberger-gruppe.de/glossar/?tx_contagged%5Bsource%5D=default&tx_contagged%5Buid%5D=68&cHash=028e746e97505b18d43848c5b4489ca9#tab%5B0%5D=0)

Bei [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=R%C3%BCckvergr%C3%B6%C3%9Ferungsger%C3%A4t&client=opera&hs=CGU&channel=suggest&hl=de&sa=X&oi=image_result_group&ved=0CBoQsAQ4CmoVChMI64yl0dSXxwIVQ1YUCh2evQ1s&tbm=isch) hat es auch viele Bilder dazu.

Auf den Treffer esse ich jetzt ein **Grießklößchensüppchenschälchen**.

Comment: *Auf den Treffer esse ich jetzt ein Grießklößchensüppchenschälchen.* – Na, wenn Du Dir daran mal nicht die Zähne ausbeißt …

Comment: Danke für ein mit Quellen belegtes Beispiel!

Answer (score 5):

U.a. in Sachsen und Sachsen-Anhalt findet man [Lößhügelländer](https://www.google.de/search?q="L%C3%B6%C3%9Fh%C3%BCgell%C3%A4nder"). Die dort vorherrschende Bodenart [Löss](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6ss) darf auch [mit 'ß' geschrieben werden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Loess).

Comment: Mit Dank an @chirlu für den Denkanstoß im Kommentar zur Frage.

Comment: Ich war unsicher, ob es _Länder_ oder doch _Lande_ wären. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Gestern fand ich eher zufällig: tränenüberströmt. Adjektive kommen bisher bei euch noch gar nicht vor. Das Wort begeisterte mich so, dass ich heute erstmals schaue, ob sich auch andere schon diesem Problem gestellt haben. 
Danke für die anderen Vorschläge.

Comment: Aber "ß" fehlt.

Answer (score -1):

Löwenkäfigtür (Ich weiß nicht, warum ich Zusätzliches hinzufügen muß...)

Comment: Dein Beispiel enthält kein ß.

Comment: Für diese braucht man einen sehr gewissenhaften Löwenkäfigtürschließer.